Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x35)
Is this error a result of MPI or memory limit?
I tried different different number of cores and different directories. However, I can not change the version of MPI because the software asks for lastest version of MPI.
[node111:1798902:0:1798902] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x35)
==== backtrace (tid:1798902) ====
0  /lib/libucs.so.0(ucs_handle_error+0x324) [0x14da10316874]
1  /lib/libucs.so.0(+0x24a9f) [0x14da10316a9f]
2  /lib/libucs.so.0(+0x24dd4) [0x14da10316dd4]
3  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-    intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x(__intel_avx_rep_memcpy+0x400) [0x792ad10]
4  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x(for__format_value+0x138) [0x78d2928]
5  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x(for_write_seq_fmt_xmit+0x164c) [0x788f54c]
6  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x(for_write_seq_fmt+0x1471) [0x788d841]
7  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x1f45850]
8  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x16f0df9]
9  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x160d8dd]
10  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0xcf27a5]
11  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x787e50]
12  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x550623]
13  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x4ed3ac]
14  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x644bf6]
15  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x43224d]
16  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x14da136460b3]
17  /home/software/espresso/qe-7.2-intel23-intelmpi/bin/qe2pert.x() [0x43216e]
=================================
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source      
libpthread-2.31.s  000014DA1CF523C0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          000000000792AD10  __intel_avx_rep_m     Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          00000000078D2928  for__format_value     Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          000000000788F54C  for_write_seq_fmt     Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          000000000788D841  for_write_seq_fmt     Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          0000000001F45850  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          00000000016F0DF9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          000000000160D8DD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          0000000000CF27A5  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          0000000000787E50  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          0000000000550623  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          00000000004ED3AC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          0000000000644BF6  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          000000000043224D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.31.so       000014DA136460B3  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
qe2pert.x          000000000043216E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/254237.masterbeta.SC: line 50: /home/wslu: Is a directory


A segmentation fault indicates that you access memory that is not allocated by the process. This can happen in your code directly or inside an (MPI) library if you pass pointers to memory space that is not allocated. To get help here please provide your code and clarify your question.

It looks like the error is in the Fortran code, and is trapped by the UCX handler. Unlikely an MPI related issue then.
